# How to set up french local of yup-locales to be the language of validation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, npm, yup

I am using yup to validate my inputs in react. The language I am using in my application is french, so I needed the validations to be in the french language.
I unstalled yup-locales using

```
npm i -s yup-locales
```

But how can I relate it with the application now?

Answer (score 0):

You must then import the French language

```
import fr from 'yup-locales/fr';
```

Then init the local schema in French

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().email().required(),
});

schema.locale(fr);
```

Comment: You can use `setLocale(fr)` before the schema too.